# 1d Stencil in x86 Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am trying to implement 1d stencil in x86 assembly in C, with the process of

```
Y[i] = X[i-3] + X[i-2] + X[i - 1] + X[i] + X[i + 1] + + X[i + 2]  + X[i + 3];
```

my c code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void stencil_function(int* X, int* Y, int n);

int main() {
    int X[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int Y[10] = { 0 };

    stencil_function(X, Y, 10);

    printf("Y = ");
    for (int i = 3; i < 10-3; i++) {
        printf("%d ", Y[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

and my assembly looks like this

```
section .text
    global stencil_function

stencil_function:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    push rdi
    push rsi

    mov rdi, qword [rbp + 16]   
    mov rsi, qword [rbp + 24]   

    xor ecx, ecx               

stencil_loop:
    mov eax, dword [rdi + rcx*4 - 12] ; Load X[i-3]
    add eax, dword [rdi + rcx*4 - 8]  ; Add X[i-2]
    add eax, dword [rdi + rcx*4 - 4]  ; Add X[i-1]
    add eax, dword [rdi + rcx*4]      ; Add X[i]
    add eax, dword [rdi + rcx*4 + 4]  ; Add X[i+1]
    add eax, dword [rdi + rcx*4 + 8]  ; Add X[i+2]
    add eax, dword [rdi + rcx*4 + 12] ; Add X[i+3]

    mov dword [rsi + rcx*4], eax      ; Store the result in Y[i]

    inc ecx                         
    cmp ecx, r8 
    jl stencil_loop              

    pop rsi
    pop rdi

    pop rbp
    ret
```

i keep getting error that says
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF644A9420D in Project1.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF644A9420D in Project1.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.

1d stencil in x86 assembly

Comment: Isn't this `mov eax, dword [rdi + rcx*4 - 12]` accessing 12 bytes *below* the start of `X` on the first iteration? And on the last iteration won't `add eax, dword [rdi + rcx*4 + 12]` access *beyond* the end of array `X`?

Comment: oh yeah, but I need to start the array index into 3 and end it into n-3

Comment: i don't know how to set the end of loop in n-3

Comment: I would write and debug the function in C first, and then translate it to assembler. The C example in the first one-line snippet will suffer the same problem. Are you supposed to 'wrap' the index (i.e use say `(i - 3 + n) % n` etc?

Comment: i already fix that in c :(

Comment: So you translated the *not-fixed* code to assembly?

Comment: If you care about performance, don't do `(i-3 + n) % n` inside the main loop in your asm.  Use a separate startup/cleanup block of code to handle the parts near the edges where wrapping is necessary.  Then the main loop is easy.  (You can optimize it by doing a sliding window (subtract the element that's no longer part of the window, add the element that's coming in) with scalar `sub` and `add`. Or there's probably a good way to take advantage of SSE2 vector instructions like `paddd xmm0, xmm1`  for 4 adds at once to generate a vector of 4 `Y[i]` results.  Probably just unaligned loads.

Comment: Your handling of arguments doesn't seem to be correct. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170.  You're trying to load them from `[rbp+16]` and `[rbp+24]`, which correspond to the shadow space, but the argument values aren't actually in the shadow space unless you put them there.  Instead, they are passed to you in `rcx, rdx, r8`.  (By the way, is it intentional that the `n` argument is unused?  Or is it supposed to correspond to the `i` in your first line?)

Comment: If you've already written and debugged the `stencil` function in C, then please post that code so that we can compare.